# Perl: How does hash assignment with 'map' work?

Tags: perl, hash, variable-assignment

I have trouble understanding how to assign to a hash using the `map` function.

Why does

`my %a = map {$_=>1 if $_>=2} (1..4);`

give me an `Odd number of elements in hash assignment` error while

`my %a = map {$_=>1 if $_>2} (1..4);`

gives me

```
$VAR1 = {
          '' => '',
          '4' => 1,
          '3' => 1
        };
```

and why is there only one empty string in the hash? If I assign to an array

`my @a = map {$_ if $_>2} (1..4);`

```
$VAR1 = [
          '',
          '',
          3,
          4
        ];
```

I get two empty strings, which makes more sense to me.

Is there a possibility to return no empty string if the condition is not met?

Comment: Use `grep` to filter.

Comment: Like this: `my @a = grep {$_ if $_>=2} (1..4); 
my %b = map {$_=>1} @a;` or is there a shorter way?

Comment: @user1981275: You don't even need the `$_ if` in the condition, just `grep { $_ >= 2 } ...`.  Once you have `@a` you can use a hash slice to populate `%b`: `my %b; @b{@a} = (1) x @a;`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`map` transforms a list into another list. In the first case, your input list is `1, 2, 3, 4`. For each member, you return a tuple if the member is `>= 2`, but otherwise, you return just a single value. The single value is returned for 1 only and causes the "odd number of elements".

In the second case, the transformation works as follows:

```
input | output
------+-------
1     | ''
2     | ''
3     | 3 => 1
4     | 4 => 1
```

If you make a hash from it, you take the first empty string as the key, the second empty string as the value, which creates "one empty string in the hash" - there are in fact two.

Answer (score 7):

Although `map` is not the best way to do this job (`grep` as pointed out would be better), it is still possible just using map with the `?` comparison:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict ;
use warnings ;
use Data::Dumper ;

my %a = map { $_>2 ? ( $_ => 1 ) : () } (1..4) ;
print Dumper( \%a ) ;
```

Returning the empty list makes `map` behave like `grep` when condition is not met.

```
>perl test.pl
$VAR1 = {
          '4' => 1,
          '3' => 1
        };
```

Comment: Perhaps rephrasing as 'returning empty list makes `map` behave like `grep` when condition is not met'

Comment: Could also write it as `map { $_ => 1 } grep { $_ > 2 } 1..4`